# c# OnTriggerStay with Collider Variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, puzzle

So I'm making a simple "puzzle" using lights. Simply, there are 3 buttons with lights on them (red, blue, green). Each button has it's own trigger volume but when I go to play, nothing prints that I even enter, stay, or leave the trigger. I've never used Collider Variables before so I feel like I'm doing something wrong (obviously or it would be working!). But then I just did "Collider entity" in the OnTriggerStay/Enter/Exit Method and it still didn't print to the console that my player was entering. Why are my Triggers not working?

[Click here for the code I'm trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og5N5.jpg)
[Click here to see how I have it in the Unity Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvxB5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Triggers only respond to other colliders that have rigid bodies on them.

Try adding a Ridgidbody component to your player and set it to kinematic.

Comment: I'm not allowed to mess with the character since it's a shared model between the class (in school). However I don't think this is the problem because all the other triggers throughout my level work. The problem is that I have 3 triggers and each one needs to recognize the player independently so that on a button push it turns off/on the correct light. Once only blue is left on an animation will play allowing progression.

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter/Stay/Exit works when the Object has a Collider Component and BluePuzzle2 doesn't have that.

Also OnTrigger function gets a Collider as parameter. Check the reference [page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

So in order to make that work put a script on every light and on that script copy this function

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    if (col.CompareTag("Player")) {
        print("Entered the trigger");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: kind of, I was trying to avoid doing it this way because this will require multiple scripts. Is there not a way to use Collider Variables?

Comment: You can use the same script for all 3 lights. I'm not sure if you can do it with Collider Variables because I have never done that or seen someone else do it.

Comment: Yeah guess that's not a thing, couldn't get it to work that way or find anything on it. I just went with making several separate scripts and everything works fine, except for the button bush audio. For some reason when I put it under my else if statement, it plays whenever the player stays in the trigger, but that's another question for another day, just glad my puzzle works! Thanks for you input!